# reading and writing to an iOS application document folder from extension

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am developing an objective-c iOS application that has an action extension.  When the action extension loads I need to read some files from the documents directory of the host application and then write a file to the host applications document directory.  I have created an application group and both the application and the extension have that application group set.  But, after setting it I still not figure out how to read and write the files from the host applications document folder from the extension. Any ideas?

Thanks,

Josh

Answer (score 1):

You cannot write to the host application itself directly. Application Group gives you access to shared filesystem container accessible by both iOS app and Extension.

To get `URL` of that shared filesystem root folder, use this call:

```
FileManager.default.containerURL(forSecurityApplicationGroupIdentifier: "group.com.something")
```

Answer (score 0):

For example: **Store and read image file**

```
// store
// goal: move image located in main bundle to shared documents folder 
// so that extension can access the image
NSString *gifPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"image" ofType:@"gif"]; // located in main bundle
NSData *gifData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:gifPath]; // image data
// get the path of shared folder
NSString *destinationPath = [[[[NSFileManager defaultManager] containerURLForSecurityApplicationGroupIdentifier:@"app.group-name"] path] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"image.gif"]; // where to store your image
[gifData writeToFile:destinationPath atomically:YES]; // write to shared document folder

// load
NSData *storedImage;
// get shared document folders path
NSString *path = [[[[NSFileManager defaultManager] containerURLForSecurityApplicationGroupIdentifier:kKeyboardSuiteName] path] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"image.gif"]];
storedImage = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:path]; //load image
```

Comment: This works from the action extension using this code: [[[NSFileManager defaultManager] containerURLForSecurityApplicationGroupIdentifier:@"group.pgp2"] path].  However when I use the same code from the application I get null, any ideas?

Comment: sorry my mistake I added it to the action but not the app so I did that and it works now

Answer (score -1):

While using the "containerURLForSecurityApplicationGroupIdentifier" is preferred and not complex at all, you can actually read and write from the Document Directory, by calling a ViewController in the main App from the Extension:

like:

```
MainViewController * mvc = [MainViewController alloc]init];
NSData * theFile =[mvc readFileFromDocFolder];
```